# Tkinter: How do I remove padding after maximize (where two frames resize to fit the window's resize)?

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

Note: This is a q/a question where I answer my own question in an answer, merely for the benefit of others (or so that people who know a better way than what I provide can provide it).

In the following example, how do I make the bottom `Text` widget fill up all the empty space that appears when you maximize the screen (and so the top `Text` widget is directly at the top after maximizing)? I don't know a reason for that extra padding. I can get rid of some of the padding by adding extra rows for the second `Text` widget to fill and using `rowspan`, but there's still some left. I do not want the top `Text` widget to have a height greater than 1.

```
from tkinter import *

tk=Tk()

tk.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
tk.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
tk.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

f=Frame(tk)
f2=Frame(tk)

f.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+W)
f2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

t=Text(f, height=1)
t2=Text(f2)
l=Label(f, text="label")
b=Button(f, text="button")

l.pack(side=LEFT)
t.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=True)
b.pack(side=LEFT)
t2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to remove the weight from row 0. When you give a row (or column...) weight, you are telling Tkinter a proportion it can use to allocate extra space. If two columns have the same weight they get the same proportion of extra space. So, with both rows having a weight of 1, they each get an equal proportion of the extra space.

By Giving only the text widget row a weight of 1, only it will grow when the window resizes.

What seems to work best in most circumstances is to have exactly one row and one column with a non-zero space -- usually a text widget or canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `weight` of row `1` to a large number like `100`. Then it will fill in the extra space appropriately (although because the button is a different height than the `Text` widget, you'll still have a little gap there). I don't know if this is the most appropriate way, but it works.

Here:

```
from tkinter import *

tk=Tk()

tk.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
tk.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
tk.rowconfigure(1, weight=100)

f=Frame(tk)
f2=Frame(tk)

f.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+W)
f2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

t=Text(f, height=1)
t2=Text(f2)
l=Label(f, text="label")
b=Button(f, text="button")

l.pack(side=LEFT)
t.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=True)
b.pack(side=LEFT)
t2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

tk.mainloop()
```